# children is not removing from firebase onclick event is written in onbindviewholder in custom recyclerview class

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

interesting thing is that toast written on remove completion is showing but value from firebase is not removing.

here is my UI image..

[image]

here is my onbindviewholder code...

```
  public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.getShopname().setText(list.get(position).getShopname());
        holder.getApmt_date().setText(list.get(position).getAppointment_date());
        Log.d("QWWQ","size="+list.get(position).getServices());
        holder.getServices().setText(list.get(position).getServices().substring(0,list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getServices().indexOf('-'))) ;
        holder.getSlot().setText(list.get(position).getSlot());
        holder.getAmount().setText(list.get(position).getAmount());

        holder.getcancelBtn().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("appointments").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot datasnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()
                             ) {
                            if(datasnapshot.child("shop_name").getValue(String.class).equals(list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getShopname())){
                                Log.d("CHHH","Users/"+FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()+"/"+datasnapshot.getKey()+"/appointment_dates/"+list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getAppointment_date());
                                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(datasnapshot.getKey()).child("appointment_dates").child(list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getAppointment_date()).removeValue(new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError error, @NonNull DatabaseReference ref) {
                                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Shops").child("appointments").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getAppointment_date()).removeValue(new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError error, @NonNull DatabaseReference ref) {
                                                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Your Appointment With "+list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getShopname()+" has been cancelled!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        });

                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }
```

Firebase database image...

[image]

Comment: You have displayed a log inside `onDatachange`. Can you tell what get's printed?

Comment: D/CHHH: Users/owRf4tqVKkbWHEUQlmrYIsXRxpO2/Sn3g0t2IslZru0cPyoFCWuGgbnV2/appointment_dates/11-4-2022............... as you can see the path is perfect and if it was not perfect then Toast message wont visible but it is.

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this article, [How to delete a record from Firestore on a RecylerView left/right swipe?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) or [How to delete multiple records from Firestore using RecyclerView multi-selection?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to not ignore errors that you get back from the APIs that you call.

In the call to `removeValue`, you'll want to check if the `error` is not `null`, and log it:

```
public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError error, @NonNull DatabaseReference ref) {
    if (error != null) {
        Log.e("Firebase", "Error deleting node", error);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Your Appointment With "+list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getShopname()+" has been cancelled!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And in your listener you should never leave `onCancelled` empty. At its minimum that should be

```
@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    throw error.toException();
}
```

Once you can read the error, you can find out what the root cause of the problem is.

Comment: I tried but still no error visible and i put toast in else part and it still runs.. can you tell me which error are you talking about

Answer (score 0):

You can use .setValue(null) instead of .removeValue to delete an item from realtime database.

Comment: no, it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving the wrong path(path which isn't Exists) for deleting that node from firebase so after correction I got my required Result.
(Note : If you give wrong path still Toast which is written in remove valueoncomplete will run.)